# How to best join one column of a data.table with another column of the same data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

### My data

I have a data.table `DT` with the current (`F0YR`) and the next (`F1YR`) fiscal year-end (FYE) encoded as integers. Since every next FYE will eventually become
a current FYE, the integer will be both in the column `F1YR` and `F0YR`. Also, my data contains monthly observations so the same FYE will be in the data set
multiple times:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID     = rep(c("A", "B"), each=9),
                 MONTH  = rep(100L:108L, times=2),
                 F0YR   = rep(c(1L, 4L, 7L), each=3, times=2),
                 F1YR   = rep(c(4L, 7L, 9L), each=3, times=2),
                 value  = c(rep(1:5, each=3), 6, 6, 7),
                 key    = "ID,F0YR")
DT
      ID MONTH F0YR F1YR value
 [1,]  A   100    1    4     1
 [2,]  A   101    1    4     1
 [3,]  A   102    1    4     1
 [4,]  A   103    4    7     2
 [5,]  A   104    4    7     2
 [6,]  A   105    4    7     2
 [7,]  A   106    7    9     3
 [8,]  A   107    7    9     3
 [9,]  A   108    7    9     3
[10,]  B   100    1    4     4
[11,]  B   101    1    4     4
...
```

### What I want to do

For every `ID` and `F1YR` combination, I want to get the value for the `ID` and `F0YR` combination. As an example: Company A had a value of `2` for `FOYR==4`. Now, 
I want an additional column for all combinations with `ID=="A"` and `F1YR==4` which is set to 2, next to the already existent value of 1.

### What I tried

```
intDT <- DT[CJ(unique(ID), unique(F0YR)), list(ID, F0YR, valueNew = value), mult="last"]
setkey(intDT, ID, F0YR)
setkey(DT, ID, F1YR)
DT <- intDT[DT]
setnames(DT, c("F0YR.1", "F0YR"), c("F0YR", "F1YR"))
DT
      ID F1YR valueNew MONTH F0YR value
 [1,]  A    4        2   100    1     1
 [2,]  A    4        2   101    1     1
 [3,]  A    4        2   102    1     1
 [4,]  A    7        3   103    4     2
 [5,]  A    7        3   104    4     2
 [6,]  A    7        3   105    4     2
 [7,]  A    9       NA   106    7     3
 [8,]  A    9       NA   107    7     3
 [9,]  A    9       NA   108    7     3
[10,]  B    4        5   100    1     4
[11,]  B    4        5   101    1     4
...
```

(Note that I use `mult="last"` here because, although the values should only change with F0YR or F1YR changes, sometimes they don't and this is just my
tie breaker).

### What I want

This looks improvable. First of all, I have to make a copy of my DT. Second, since I join basically the same `data.table`, all the column names have the same name
and I have to rename them. I thought that a `self join` would be the way forward, but I tried and tried and couldn't get a nice solution. I have the hope
that there is something easy out there which I just don't see...Does anyone have a clue? Or is my data set up in such a way that it is actually hard
(maybe because I have monthly observations, but want to join only quarterly or yearly changing values).

Comment: I don't think it's needed for this question but `:=` by group is working now in 1.8.1, and could be used for this perhaps. R-Forge is building ok and the binary installs ok (in R 2.15.0 since R-Forge only buids for latest) using `install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. Check that `test.data.table()` returns "653 tests completed ok" to be sure it's the latest version. See latest NEWS to see if any new features are useful for this one.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Very nice! I just tried that out. Looks like it works for overwriting an existing column, but not yet for creating a new one. Is that right?

Comment: @Josh Great. No, it should add new columns fine. You can even subassign to a new column and it'll populate the rest of the column with `NA` for you. If neither works please file a bug report or new question. Make sure `test.data.table()` returns `653 tests ok` to rule out somehow using an older revision of v1.8.1.

Comment: @MatthewDowle That is indeed very nice. I didn't know how simple it is to install the package that way...Anyways, I also don't see how `:=` by group can help here. Tried it for an hour and couldn't figure anything out. So I guess my solution is OK. Joining one data.table by two columns of that data.table is a very specific use case anyway.

Comment: No problem, have added an answer. Gone straight to `:=` by group, grouping by `i` not `by`, and using join inherited scope (`V1` comes from `i` scope) to boot.  Didn't exactly plan to go that far in the first demo of `:=` by group, but that's just the way it worked it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In use cases like this, the mantra "aggregate first, then join with that" often helps. So, starting with your `DT`, and using v1.8.1 :

```
> agg = DT[,last(value),by=list(ID,F0YR)]
> agg
   ID F0YR V1
1:  A    1  1
2:  A    4  2
3:  A    7  3
4:  B    1  4
5:  B    4  5
6:  B    7  7
```

I called it `agg` because I couldn't think of a better name. In this case you wanted `last` which isn't really an aggregate as such, but you know what I mean.

Then update `DT` by reference by group. Here we're grouping by `i`.

```
setkey(DT,ID,F1YR)
DT[agg,newcol:=V1]
    ID MONTH F0YR F1YR value newcol
 1:  A   100    1    4     1      2
 2:  A   101    1    4     1      2
 3:  A   102    1    4     1      2
 4:  A   103    4    7     2      3
 5:  A   104    4    7     2      3
 6:  A   105    4    7     2      3
 7:  A   106    7    9     3     NA
 8:  A   107    7    9     3     NA
 9:  A   108    7    9     3     NA
10:  B   100    1    4     4      5
11:  B   101    1    4     4      5
12:  B   102    1    4     4      5
13:  B   103    4    7     5      7
14:  B   104    4    7     5      7
15:  B   105    4    7     5      7
16:  B   106    7    9     6     NA
17:  B   107    7    9     6     NA
18:  B   108    7    9     7     NA
```

Is that right?  Not sure I fully followed. Those ops should be very fast, without any copies, and should scale to large data. At least, that's the intention.

Comment: Great answer, Matthew, many thanks. This does exactly what I want. One question though: Your answer looks, except for the `newcol:=V1` part, pretty straightforward and I thought I tried every possible combination, which includes the aggregate first and then join mantra. Therefore, I just run your answer with `DT[agg]` instead of `DT[agg,newcol:=V1]`. Now, my DT looks pretty different: it only has 14 rows and some NAs for MONTH. Why is that? I just thought the `newcol:=V1` renames V1 to newcol. What do I miss here?

Comment: @Christoph_J Great. No, `:=` never renames columns. `setnames()` renames columns. `:=` assigns by reference to existing or new columns. The part you may be missing is that non-join columns in `i` (i.e. columns not involved in the join, in this case `V1`) can be used in `j`, thanks to join inherited scope. Try removing the `newcol:=` bit instead to see that. Or study the example in `?data.table` of `# join inherited scope`. `DT[agg]` returns `NA`s for the no matches. `:=` on the other hand updates `DT` by reference; there's nothing to update when the `i` row has no match in `DT`.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into that! Your package has just too much cool stuff to keep up with it ;-)