# R data.table count panel data

Tags: r, count, data.table

I have panel data (subject/year) for which I would like to only keep subjects who appear the maximum number of times per year.  The data set is large so I am using the data.table package.  Is there a more elegant solution than what I have tried below?

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(SUBJECT=c(rep('John',3), rep('Paul',2), 
                           rep('George',3), rep('Ringo',2), 
                           rep('John',2), rep('Paul',4), 
                           rep('George',2), rep('Ringo',4)), 
                 YEAR=c(rep(2011,10), rep(2012,12)), 
                 HEIGHT=rnorm(22), 
                 WEIGHT=rnorm(22))
DT

DT[, COUNT := .N, by='SUBJECT,YEAR']
DT[, MAXCOUNT := max(COUNT), by='YEAR']

DT <- DT[COUNT==MAXCOUNT]
DT <- DT[, c('COUNT','MAXCOUNT') := NULL]
DT
```

Comment: So essentially you want a data.table with all data from the most data-rich year for each beatle?

Comment: Come to think of it, it'd be nice if `data.table` had some of the same `by` capabilities in the `i` expression as it does in `j` expressions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll view this as *elegant* but how about :

```
DT[, COUNT := .N, by='SUBJECT,YEAR']
DT[, .SD[COUNT == max(COUNT)], by='YEAR']
```

That's essentially how to apply `by` to the `i` expression as @SenorO commented.  You'll still need `[,COUNT:=NULL]` afterwards but for one temporary column rather than two.

We do discourage `.SD` though for speed reasons, but hopefully we'll get to this feature request soon so that advice can be dropped: [FR#2330 Optimize .SD[i] query to keep the elegance but make it faster unchanged.](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2330&group_id=240&atid=978).

A different approach is as follows. It's faster and idiomatic but may be considered less elegant.

```
# Create a small aggregate table first. No need to use := on the big table.
i = DT[, .N, by='SUBJECT,YEAR']

# Find the even smaller subset. (Do as much as we can on the small aggregate.)
i = i[, .SD[N==max(N)], by=YEAR]

# Finally join the small subset of key values to the big table
setkey(DT, YEAR, SUBJECT)
DT[i]
```

Something similar is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11037016/403310).